# A Integral question

Tags: mathematical-statistics, integral

I am having problem with integral:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{2\pi} e^{-itx} \left( 0.5 \left( e^{-4t^2} + 1 +\cos(t) + \cos(2t) \right)\right) \,dt$$

@DilipSarwate I have proved lim sup(cf)=1 when t goes to infinity, thus here the limits of the integral becomes (-pi,pi), then I break up the sum in to four integrals.

Comment: Hint: break up your integral into the sum of four integrals and look at a table of _Fourier transforms_. The first will give you something like $a\exp(-bx^2)$ for values of $a$ and $b$ that you need to determine. The latter three will give things that are called _generalized functions_ or _distributions_ (with different meaning than is used in this forum) or _impulses_ or _Dirac deltas_ depending on whom you are talking to.

Comment: This question will fit better in math.stackexchange.com

Comment: @DilipSarwate I have proved lim sup(cf)=1 when t goes to infinity, thus here the limits of the integral becomes (-pi,pi), then I break up the sum in to four integrals. and I integrate the second part exp(-itx)(1+cost+cos2t) from -pi to pi and i get 1/4 when x=0,-1,1,2,-2. However, now I cannot use gaussian integral for the first part (exp(-itx)exp(-4t^2)) since the limits is no longer from minus infinity to infinity.  I am stuck at here...

Comment: I have no idea as to why the limits on the integral change from $\pm\infty$ to $\pm\pi$ just because the limsup of _something_ (what's $cf$, anyway?) is $1$. The value $1/4$ that you claim you get is _not_ the correct value of any integral that you ought to be evaluating. The value of the integral shown works out to be of the form $$a\exp(-bx^2) + c_0\delta(x) + c_1(\delta(x-1)+\delta(x+1))+c_2(\delta(x-2)+\delta(x+2))$$ where $\delta(x)$ is the Dirac delta or impulse which has the property that $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)\delta(x-a)\,\mathrm dx= g(a)$$ provided $g(x)$ is continuous at $x=a$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate The original problem has two cfs(characteristics functions), which are phi_1(t)=exp(-4t^2) and the other is equal to the latter three terms and we need to identify the distribution of 1/2(phi_1+phi_2).I am thinking to prove lim sup(phi_1)=0 to show the first part is a continuous case that we can apply the formula to get the pdf on (-infinity, infinity). Second, i am thinking to show the second part is discrete case and each part is equal to 2pi when x=-2,-1,0,1,2. Thus the value of this integral is equal to (1/2pi)(1/2)(1/2)(2pi)=1/4 for each x value.

Comment: The distribution whose characteristic function is $\frac{\phi_1(t)+\phi_2(t)}{2}$ is a _mixed_ distribution. The CDF is continuous and strictly increasing everywhere _except_ at $x=-2,-1,0,1,2$ where it is discontinuous with upwards jumps (and the jumps _cannot_ be $\frac{1}{4}$ at these $5$ points). In any case, mixed distributions need special handling to point out which parts correspond to the continuous pdf and which to the discrete pmf. The Dirac delta can be used iin this handling.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Thanks very much for the explanation, and I think i have figured out this problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is off-topic---belongs on math SE (but to old)